# remove scroll bar in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<span class="education"style="font-size:170%;line-height:150%;">&nbsp;Education
<br>
          <small style=" color:gray;font-size:60%;">&nbsp;
        Indian Institute of Managment,2009-2011
      </small>
<br>

      <small style=" color:gray;font-size:60%;">&nbsp;Indian Institute of   
        Technology,2004-2008
      </small>
<br>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#education" style="float:right;font-size:60%;">
     <small> Edit&nbsp;
     </small>
       </a>
       <div class="modal fade " id="education">
     <div class="modal-dialog ">
       <div class="modal-content light">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
           </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Education
           </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <form>
             <fieldset>
                   <label  for="post-graduation">post-graduation:
           </label>
               <input type="text" name="post-graduation" id="inputbox" 
            class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
           <label  for="graduation">graduation:
           </label>
               <input type="text" name="graduation" id="inputbox" 
            class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->          
     </span>
```

It is my code. I want a modal when I click on edit button. The modal was appear in my page and disappear when I click on close button. But with modal it also show scroll bar. How can I remove scrollbar from my code?

Answer (score 7):

In bootstrap 3 the CSS puts the second bar in there (modal class). You can change it like:

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should hide the scroll from the bootstrap class and then remove the `margin-right` of the `body`.

Here the `css` code:

```
#modalElementId
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and in the `show.bs.modal` event:

```
$('#modalElementId').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('body').css("margin-right", "0px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     .modal-open{
       margin-right:0px !important;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set height for modal body

```
 .modal-body {
        max-height: 600px;
    }
```

Comment: this may help u...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508576/twitter-bootstrap-modal-scrolling-issue

Answer (score 0):

Your need remove the `class` `modal-open` in the `body`, check:

```
$('#modalElementId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I want to display an image on full screen so to achieve this I have to remove the modal padding(to display it over the scrollbar) and also adding some CSS. Example:

```
<!-- Image Modal -->
<div class="modal fade p-0" id="zoomImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="zoomImageModal"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-full" role="img">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <div class="m-auto">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{zoomPathImage}}" alt="zoomPathImage" [title]="zoomPathImage">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.modal-full {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.modal-full .modal-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

**Note: I am using Bootstrap4**